# Why is the JDA returning a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, discord

I'm currently trying to use the `getMemberById()` method, but it always returns a null, even when I give it specific instructions or a specific ID that I know is correctly formatted.

```
public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        Member member = event.getGuild().getMemberById("500364917736734734");
}
```

I know this ID is valid because when I use a boolean to detect if a user's ID is equal to this specific ID, it returns as non-null. It gives me `true` when it is.

Your help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [retrieveMemberById](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#retrieveMemberById(long)) instead:

```java
public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
    event.getGuild().retrieveMemberById("500364917736734734").queue(member -> {
        ...
    });
}
```

This is necessary because the member might not be cached when you call `getMemberById`. By default, JDA will not load all members into cache on startup. For this purpose, a number of methods are available to load members dynamically. This is further explained in the [JDA Wiki](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/Gateway-Intents-and-Member-Cache-Policy).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Thanks, bud, this worked.

Answer (score 0):

It is very well possible that you are calling `getMemberById(String)` while the ID should be entered as a `long` into `getMemberById(long)` [JavaDocs](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#getMemberById(long)). Considering that you might want to get the `Member` for which this event fires, you should use `GuildMessageReceivedEvent.getMember()` if that's the case.

Comment: I thought of that, so I tried using a `long` value instead, the same exact thing happened. I got a `NullPointerException` when it was executed. It can be entered as both a `String` and a `long` value, I checked the docs. Also, I do not want to get the member from which the event fires, that was just an example, I was confused as to why it gave me a null exception. Thanks

Comment: Did you also confirm that the user you're trying to get is in the same guild as for which the event fires? Having that user in a different guild would also explain the null return.

Comment: Yes, I got him from that guild specifically.

Comment: Reading the [docs](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#getMemberById(long)), this method only returns cached users. If you use the 'wrong'  `MemberCachePolicy`, then this user might have not been cached, making the method return null.

Comment: So I need to make a cache for the members?

Comment: It looks like it. Read [this](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/utils/MemberCachePolicy.html) to get more information on caching and which method to call to set this up.